# Fetch json value correctly and convert into integers using python3 and upload directly into database but in python code there is some error generated

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, iot

In this code I want to fetch JSON value from https://thingspeak.com/channels/1441388/feed.json  of field1 and field2 and upload into my local database using python3 but the error comes out in "first" variable that "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

```
import urllib.request
import json
import mysql.connector
url = "https://thingspeak.com/channels/1441388/feed.json"
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="123",database="path")

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    s=url.read()
data = json.dumps(s.decode("utf-8"))
N=10
for num in reversed(range(N + 1)) :   # fetch last ten data 
    first = (data['feeds'][num]['field1'])  # fetch field1 data from JSON
    print("first",first)
    second = data['feeds'][num]['field2']
    print("second",second)
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    insert_stmt = ("INSERT INTO details(Distance,water_level,Connected_device)"
       "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")    
    data = (first,second,'Arduino & GPRS')
    
    try:
        cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
        mydb.commit()
        #cursor.close()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
    except:
        mydb.rollback()
```

**I get this output
**

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IOT\Blind Stick\fetch.py", line 14, in <module>
    first = list(data['feeds'][num]['field1'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers**
```

> So I am wondering what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Your `data` is a json-formatted string, but you're using it as if it was a dictionary, hence the error. Maybe you wanted to use `json.loads` instead of `json.dumps`?

Comment: first 111
second 20
1 record inserted.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IOT\Blind Stick\fetch.py", line 13, in <module>
    first = (data['feeds'][num]['field1'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: What did you change? This time it seems on the second iteration your data contain a tuple

Answer (score 0):

use `json.loads` instead of `.dumps`.

Comment: I used it json.loads then the following output is given:first 111
second 20
1 record inserted.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IOT\Blind Stick\fetch.py", line 13, in <module>
    first = (data['feeds'][num]['field1'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Try removing the surrounding parentheses. But please note that you are not iterating over the last ten indexes. You shoud write your for loop as:
``for num in range(N):`` and when you are accessing the index use it as a negative number ``first = data['feeds'][-num]['field1']``

Comment: Same output: first 111 second 20 1 record inserted. Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\IOT\Blind Stick\fetch.py", line 13, in <module> first = (data['feeds'][num]['field1']) TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: You still have the surrounding parenthesis (I don't know which python version are you using but it may create a tuple instead of a value).
Could it be that you get a different JSON ? The current code assumes that all the data is there and has the same structure. Try printing the string before loads and then the data dictionary.

Comment: I am currently using python 3.9.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235133/discussion-between-bicky-yadav-and-florin-ciurcanu).